# ruby regex about escape a escape

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regex in Ruby to test a string such as:

`"GET \"anything/here.txt\""`

the point is, everything can be in the outer double quote, but all double quotes in the outer double quotes must be escaped by back slash(otherwise it doesnt match). So for example

`"GET "anything/here.txt""` 

this will not be a proper line.

I tried many ways to write the regex but doest work. can anyone help me with this? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use positive lookbehind:

`/\A"((?<=\\)"|[^"])*"\z/`

This does exactly what you asked for: "if a double quote appears inside the outer double quotes without a backslash prefixed, it doesn't match."

Some comments:

`\A`,`\z`: These match only at the *beginning* and *end* of the string. So the pattern has to match against the *whole* string, not a part of it.
`(?<=)`: This is the syntax for positive lookbehind; it asserts that a pattern must match *directly before* the current position. So `(?<=\\)"` matches "a double quote which is preceded by a backslash".
`[^"]`: This matches "any character which is not a backslash".

One point about this regex, is that it *will* match an inner double quote which is preceded by *two* backslashes. If that is a problem, post a comment and I'll fix it.

If your version of Ruby doesn't have lookbehind, you could do something like:

`/\A"(\\.|[^"\\])*"\z/`

Note that unlike the first regexp, this one does not count a double backslash as escaping a quote (rather, the first backslash escapes the second one), so `"\\""` will not match.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much. This is a very good way to do this. But one problem is, my ruby version is 1.8.6 which is not support the `?`. Do you have any idea about this? thank you

Comment: @AllanJiang, I'll add another solution which doesn't use lookbehind.

Comment: Thank you it works the way I said... but I found another trouble with your answer... in my situation, I want to make it match only the double quotes are escaped in the outer double quote, but in this case it does't work when things like this happens `"GET /class/\"notes\".txt\"` (the last double qoute is also escaped)which means the outer quote is escaped as well. I dont want the outer double quote to be escaped in this case... but cannot come up with a solution.... Not sure if you can fix this? thank you

Comment: oo I got it actually it should be `["](\\.|[^"])*[^\\]["]`in this case

Comment: The only weakness of that one is that it will not match a double backslash right before the closing quote. If you want to count double backslashes as a literal backslash (not an escape), consider the regexp in my (now edited) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
/"(?<method>[A-Z]*)\s*\\\"(?<file>[^\\"]*)\\""/
```

See it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Ktn6e7UzfR).

Edit:

```
"(?<method>[A-Z]*)\s(?<content>(\\\"|[a-z\/\.]*)*)"
```

See it [here](http://rubular.com/r/ZymE8HhxQO).

Edit 2: without (? ...) sequence (for Ruby 1.8.6):

```
"([A-Z]*)\s((\\\"|[a-z\/\.]*)*)"
```

Rubular [here](http://rubular.com/r/P2zwrihG3P).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is a question that the `\"` in the line can appear anywhere, for example it wont work with this `"GET /class/\"notes\".txt"` So I am just wondering there is a way to do this: "if a double quote appears in the outer double quote without a backslash prefixed, it doesnt match"

Comment: @AllanJiang, see updated answer. Is this the behaviour you expect?

Comment: Updated again for older Ruby version.

Comment: Hi Louism, Thank you for your answer. Have you tried that in rubular? it says `Rubular suspects this regex will take forever to parse. Regexes of this sort make Rubular sad. Adjust the regex or else wait a few minutes and try again.` to me...

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on Rubular successfully:

`\"GET \\\".*\\\"\"`

Breakdown:
\" - Escape the " for the regex string, meaning the literal character "
GET - Assuming you just want GET than this is explicit
\\" - Escape \ and " to get the literal string \"
.* - 0 or more of any character other than \n
\\"\" - Escapes for the literal \""

Comment: @andrewrockwell hi this works for my example thank you. But the `\"` in the outer double quotes can be anywhere else. for example: `"GET /class/\"notes\".txt"` and your answer will not work for this. Please take a look at my comment at louism's answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a regex is really your best tool here, but if you insist on using one, I recommend thinking of the string as a sequence of tokens: a quote, then a series of things that are either `\\`, `\"` or anything that isn't a quote, then a closing quote at the end. So this:

```
^"(\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"$
```